# How can administrators of WebSite can turn of CloudFlare for me?

Tags: cloudflare, archive

We’re organization, which trying to archive russian independent media. But some websites block acces via Cloudflare. Can we get permission from the media to access their site so that Cloudflare doesn’t block us?

Now we're trying to archive this websites using selenium but this is not comfortable for us

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare configured from the that "media" side, you can't do anything with that without getting permissions from that media (you can try to connect with them via e-mail for example).
Or, you can always use VPN for getting access.